# Is there music library software for OSX that works like Picasa does to replace iPhoto?

Tags: macos, itunes, software-recommendation

I'm kinda new to OS X, but loving it. I have decided to replace iPhoto with Picasa and want a replacement for iTunes that works more like Picasa.

There are just some apps that really get on my nerves. For instance, it really bothered me how iPhoto moved all my photos that I had carefully organized, to some random folder. So finally I decided to switch to [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/), which has the exact same functionality and doesn't move any of my files.

Recently I'm having same troubles with iTunes: I can't find where the music files I just imported from a CD are, and I just found out that iTunes creates a huge folder where it copies all your music files (this folder, in my case, is over 50 Gb). All of this is really annoying.

Is there any option for iTunes, such as Picasa for iPhoto?

**EDIT:** I'm basically looking for something to organize and play my music nicely, with a good OS X integration. I don't have a iOS device, so no sync or cloud service is actually needed.

Comment: A user pointed to a close question where someone wanted to have [multiple iTunes libraries so that one was lean and the other inclusive of thousands of items](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5808), but I don't see that as a duplicate since you are looking for software to entirely replace iTunes with similar functionality, but different design.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some objective things you need your software to do and list some iTunes functions you could do without. Clearly, nothing will work with iTunes in the could, syncing content to iOS devices, play music, rent movies - do everything iTunes does. The more you can list what you really need, the better we can help you.

Comment: And if you are just worried about iTunes messing with your folder structure there are ways to prevent this directly in iTunes.

Answer (score 4):

If you like the basic functionality of iTunes, you can just disable its folder management activities in iTunes Preferences by removing the highlighted check marks below:

[image]

(English):

[image]